# How to retrieve other columns when performing an aggregate function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, greatest-n-per-group

I've been trying to retrieve other columns from a table in which I'm performing an aggregate function to get the minimum number by date, this is an example of the data:

```
id   resource   date               quality   ask   ask_volume
1    1          2020-06-08 10:50   0         6.9   5102
2    1          2020-06-08 10:50   1         6.8   2943
3    1          2020-06-08 10:50   2         6.9   25338
4    1          2020-06-08 10:50   3         7.0   69720
5    1          2020-06-08 10:50   4         7.0   9778
6    1          2020-06-08 10:50   5         7.0   297435
7    1          2020-06-08 10:40   0         6.6   611
8    1          2020-06-08 10:40   1         6.6   4331
9    1          2020-06-08 10:40   2         6.7   1000
10   1          2020-06-08 10:40   3         7.0   69720
11   1          2020-06-08 10:40   4         7.0   9778
12   1          2020-06-08 10:40   5         7.0   297435
...
```

This is the desired result I'm trying to get, so I can perform a weighted average on it:

```
date               ask   ask_volume
2020-06-08 10:50   6.8   2943
2020-06-08 10:40   6.6   4331
...
```

Though both `quality` 0 and `quality` 1 have the same `ask`, `quality` 1 shall be chosen because its `ask_volume` is higher.

I have tried the classic:

```
SELECT date, min(ask) FROM table GROUP BY date;
```

But adding `ask_volume` to the column list will force me to add it to the `GROUP BY` as well, messing up the result.

The problems are:

1. How can I get the corresponding `ask_volume` of the minimum `ask` displayed in the result?
2. And, if there are two records with the same `ask` value on the same `date`, how can I get `ask_volume` to show the one with the highest value?

I use PostgreSQL, but SQL from a different database will help me get the idea as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard SQL, you would use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by date order by ask, ask_volume desc) rn
    from mytable 
) t
where rn = 1
```

In Postgres this is better suited for `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (date) *
from mytable
order by ask, ask_volume desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (date) t.*
from (select t.*,
order by date, ask, ask_volume desc;
```

I find your `date` column confusing.  It has a time component, so the name is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are simpler and better, but here is an alternative to get around your aggregation problem. You could use a subquery to only include `max` ask_volume per date per ask before you get the `min` ask per date.

```
select date, min(ask), max(ask_volume) 
from t
where (date, ask_volume) in (select date, max(ask_volume) 
                             from t
                             group by date, ask)
group by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT ON` has already been suggested, but in imperfect ways. (The currently accepted answer is incorrect.) That's how you do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (date) *
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY date, ask, ask_volume DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Most importantly, leading expressions in `ORDER BY` must be in the set of expressions in `DISTINCT ON`. In other words for the simple case, `date` must be the first `ORDER BY` expression.

While `null` values have not been ruled out (with a `NOT NULL` constraint), you must add `NULLS LAST` or get `null` values first in descending order.

Detailed explanation:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)